# How to show error when dividing by zero c++

Tags: c++, calculator, division, zero

I'm trying to create simple calculator. It works just fine for every operator except for '/'.
But when num2 = 0 program stops completely. I've tried using conditional statements to output error message when num2 = 0, but it's not working.

Here's code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;


int SumNum(int& a, int& b);
int SubNum(int& a, int& b);
int DivNum(int& a, int& b);
int MulNum(int& a, int& b);


int main()
{
    char op;
    int* num1 = new (nothrow) int;
    int* num2 = new (nothrow) int;
    cout << "Enter operator either + or - or * or /: ";
    cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter first operand: ";
    cin >> *num1;
    cout<< "Enter second operand: ";
    cin >> *num2;

    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
        cout << "Result is : " << SumNum(*num1, *num2) << endl;
        break;

    case '-':
        cout << "Result is : " << SubNum(*num1, *num2) << endl;
        break;

    case '/':
        cout << "Result is : " << DivNum(*num1, *num2) << endl;
        break;

    case '*':
        cout << "Result is : " << MulNum(*num1, *num2) << endl;
        break;

   default:
        cout << "Incorrect operator";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int SumNum(int& a, int& b) {
    return a + b;
}
int SubNum(int& a, int& b) {
    return a - b;
}
int DivNum(int& a, int& b) {
    return a / b;
}
int MulNum(int& a, int& b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

Comment: Why are `num1` and `num2` pointers? Why are you passing the numbers to the functions by reference?

Comment: I don't see any conditional statements that check if `num2` is 0

Comment: What did you try?  Something like `if (b == 0) // handle error` inside `DivNum`, or before calling it, should work fine.  Note that this has to come *before* the division; dividing by zero is undefined behavior in C++ and there is no portable way to recover once you've done it.

Comment: num1 and num2 are pointers because its my c++ homework and that was the condition

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory for your variables?  There is no need to do that in C++.

Comment: In addition, why do you use `nothrow` version of `new`, without testing for the allocation result?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the division case with something like this:

```cpp
case '/':
    if (*num2 == 0) {
        cout << "Error: You can't divide by 0!" << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << "Result is : " << DivNum(*num1, *num2) << endl;
    break;
```